# How to retrieve one record at a time from SQL Server database in MVC using button click

Tags: jquery, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I want to display one by one record from database using button click. This is my action method in the controller

```
public ActionResult ApplyJobs(int? id, int x)
{
    TblConsultancies consultancyJobs = _obj.TblConsultancies.ToList().Skip(x).FirstOrDefault();
    return View(consultancyJobs);
}
```

JQuery AJAX code:

```
 <script>
        var numberofRecords;
        $(document).ready(function () { 
            numberofRecords = 1;
        },
            function FetchRecord(){
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "/Home/ApplyJobs",
                    data: {
                        recNo: numberofRecords
                    },
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (response) {
                        numberofRecords+=1;
                        alert("success...");
                        var cars = response.d;
                        $('#output').empty();
                        $.each(cars, function (index, car) {
                            $('#output').append('<tr><td>' + car.Name + '</td></tr>');
                        });
                    },
                    failure: function (msg) {
                        $('#output').text(msg);
                    }
                });
            }

        );

    </script>
```

HTML:

```
 <div id="output">@Model.Name</div>
```

From the above code when I enter manually `/Home/ApplyJobs?x=1`.

It's working. But I want to display only when I click on Next button.

How can I get one by one record? Thanks.

Comment: I commented on 6 major errors in the code in your now deleted previous question, none of which you have addressed here. This is easy enough to solve but without understanding exactly what you want to display I cant give you the correct solution. Do you want to return a view, or do you want to return json? Do you initially display the first `TblConsultancies` object when you first render the view? Is there anything else that your displaying other that a `TblConsultancies` object?

Comment: I want to display 'Name' which is present in the TblConsultancies table. But here the condition is ,it should display only one record at a time. If I click on Next button it should get the next record from the table.

Comment: I understand that. Is the `Name` property of `TblConsultancies` the only thing you want to update in the view (i.e. display it in the `<div id="output">`)?

Comment: And when you first display the view, do you display anything in that `<div>` (i.e. the name of the first `TblConsultancies`) or is it just blank?

Comment: Bydefault when I click on ApplyJobs tab it should display first record (Only name) from TblConsultancies. Later when I click Next button it should pull next record. I want to display only Name in this div.                                  '<div id="output">@Model.Name</div>

Comment: OK, That exactly what I have shown in my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First the action method. You are wanting to return the next `Name` property of `TblConsultancies` ordered by its `ID` property. Therefore you need to pass in the current `ID` and return the next `ID` and `Name`

```cs
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult ApplyJobs(int id)
{
  // Get the next TblConsultancy
  var next = _obj.TblConsultancies.OrderBy(j => j.ID).Where(j => j.ID > id).FirstOrDefault();
  if(next == null)
  {
    return null;
  }
  else
  {
    // Select the ID and Name
    var data = new
    {
      ID = next.ID,
      Name = next.Name
    };
    return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
  }
}
```

View (don't mix markup and behavior - use [Unobtrusive Javascript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript))

```html
<div id="output">@Model.Name</div>
<button id="next" type="button" title="Next">Next</button>
```

Script

```js
var ID = '@Model.ID'; // or var ID = 1; if your not initially rendering an object
var url = '@Url.Action("ApplyJobs", "Home")'; // don't hard code url's!
var output = $('#output'); // cache it
$('#next').click(function() {
  $.getJSON(url, { id: ID }, function(data) {
    if(data) {
      ID = data.ID; // reset the current ID
      output.html(data.Name); // display the name
    } else {
      // no more objects - display message, disable the button?
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Error '***.TblConsultancies' does not contain a definition for 'Select' and no extension method 'Select' accepting a first argument of type 'JobMessengerUI.TblConsultancies' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.JsonResult ApplyJobs(Int32)' in 'JobMessengerUI.Controllers.HomeController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
Parameter name: parameters

Comment: That's because your not passing an ID to `ApplyJobs(int id)`.Note the comment in first line of the script. If you are not initially passing and object and have access to its ID, the you need to pass something (or change the method to `ApplyJobs(int? id)` then if `id` is null, return the first object in the collection. You need to learn to debug both you server an client side code so you can see what actually going on.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of registering onclick event of the Next button un onclick property on the object instead.

```
<input id="btnNext" type="button" title="Next" value="Next" onclick="FetchRecord()" />

var numberofRecords;
$(document).ready(function () {
    numberofRecords = 1;
}
function FetchRecord(){
    $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "/Home/ApplyJobs",
                data: {
                    recNo: numberofRecords
                },
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (response) {
                    numberofRecords+=1;
                    alert("success...");
                    var cars = response.d;
                    $('#output').empty();
                    .each(cars, function (index, car) {
                        $('#output').append('<tr><td>' + car.Name + '</td></tr>');
                    });
                },
                failure: function (msg) {
                    $('#output').text(msg);
                }
            });
        });
}
```

And instead of returning ActionResult try returning JsonResult instead

```
public JsonResult ApplyJobs(int recNo)
{
    TblConsultancies consultancyJobs = _obj.TblConsultancies.ToList().Skip(recNo).FirstOrDefault();

    return Json(consultancyJobs);
}
```

Comment: Error: The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'recNo' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.JsonResult ApplyJobs(Int32)' in '***.Controllers.HomeController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
Parameter name: parameters

Comment: The value of variable "numberofRecords" is set to 1 at the document load. How could it be null. Is there any piece of code here you set it to null? If so just change the signature of the method to public JsonResult ApplyJobs(int? recNo). But your linQ might fail this time.

Comment: have you noticed  `numberofRecords` has different scope?

Comment: Yes, it is global. Accessible everywhere until you are on the file. You are, aren't you?

Comment: Updated my code. As you said. But it is not working.